# How to carry out adjusted indirect comparison or 'Bucher method' meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, relative-risk, systematic, network-meta-analysis

I have carried out a pairwise meta-analysis of Drug 1 vs. placebo and a pairwise meta-analysis of Drug 2 vs. placebo (I have used RevMan software to do this). From each meta-analyses I have an overall estimate of the log of the risk ratio, accompanied by a standard error.

I want to use the 'Bucher method', or adjusted indirect comparison to get a difference between the two overall estimates (estimate the risk ratio for Drug 2 vs. Drug 1) and obtain an estimate of its variance by adding the variances of the two overall estimates.

However I am not sure how to do this. Essentially all I want to do is for a given outcome determine which drug is better, but I am stuck on having done the pair-wise meta-analysis and don't know how to proceed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the two groups of studies are independent then
http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:comp_two_independent_estimates
shows you how to do this in `R` but I think it should be portable to other software although possibly not to RevMan (which I have never used).

Answer (score 1):

Adjusted indirect comparisons are a special case of network meta-analyses, where there is no closed loop in the evidence network. For further details, You can refer to several useful websites, books, and articles, as compiled by [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.it/scholar?hl=en&q=network%20meta-analysis). For instance, the website from the [Cochrane Collaboration](http://methods.cochrane.org/cmi/network-meta-analysis-toolkit) is very complete, and this article by [Greco et al](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26157739) is also a useful summary.

Focusing on the Bucher method, the idea behind it is quite simple: if you have trials comparing A vs B and providing an effect estimate of such comparison (e.g. such as log risk ratio [logRR] with corresponding variance [var]), and then trials comparing C vs B (e.g. also providing logRR and var), then the indirect comparison effect estimate of A vs C will be the difference between the two effect estimates above (i.e. logRR of A vs C will be yielded b the difference of logRR of A vs B minus logRR of C vs B). The variance will be instead the sum (not the difference!) of the two variances. From the variance you can easily obtain the standard error (SE) as var=SE^2, and the other way around. Finally, from logRR and SE you can get p values and confidence intervals.

Focusing more on your case, you could use simply Excel and a few formulas, for instance using this [Excel sheet](http://www.metcardio.org/macros/IMT.xls) which was built mainly for educational purposes. However, for consistency and style I recommend you use Stata or R, especially if you want to publish your findings in a scholarly venue.

Given that you may get several ancillary analyses, including evidence networks and funnel plots, the best option in my opinion is to rely on `mvmeta` (as well as `network graphs`) in Stata, or `netmeta` in R. They are both frequentist and almost correspond to the Bucher method when only indirect comparisons are envisioned.

I cannot run it, so I cannot recommend it to you, but Stata should also have a specific command for this, `indirect`, by [Miladinovic et al](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0325).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Stata or R sounds really complicated. I am an undergraduate student doing a systematic review (dissertation) on 2 drugs to determine which, (if any) is more efficacious. I have looked into network meta-analysis however unfortunately it is quite above my scope to comprehend it, so I thought to follow Bucher's method indirect comparison. Do you know if there is a simple way of differentiating between 2 different risk ratios (Drug 1 vs placebo, Drug 2 vs placebo to get and idea of Drug 1 vs Drug 2)? thanks!

Comment: I have edited my reply providing some suggestions for beginners. Note though that if you want to submit it for a scholarly publication you will need to do it proficiently.

Comment: Dear Guiseppe, thank you very much! May I ask, when obtaining risk ratio from Revman, is given as logRR? for e.g. I have got 1.54 [0.98, 2.42] M-H. Would I need to log1.54? or is it already in the log format? Thank you in advance.

Comment: RevMan provides you RR, not logRR. You thus need to log-transform it (natural logarith). If the SE is not reported, you can back calculate it from the 95% confidence interval, which is indeed built as: exp ( logRR +/- 1.96 * SE ).

Comment: Dear @guiseppe , the Excel sheet you provided looks at Odds Ratio, I have risk ratio for the two drugs, could you tell me how I can use it for risk ratios please. I do apologise, I have very little experience in using computer programs and in meta-analytical methods. Many thanks